# Async call in vscode Jupiter's cells - it doesn't work

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I use python with VSCode, the goal what I want to achieve is simple: - launch asynchronously task in one Jupiter cell and then stop it in the cell below. But in my case it doesn't work - when I launch the async task in one cell the task in another cell waiting for the end of the first cell . Could somebody explain what I do wrong? here is my code

cell 1

```py
import asyncio

import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

i = 0
is_cancel_request = False
async def some_async_function(i):    
    while is_cancel_request == False:
        i = i+1
        print(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

await some_async_function(i)
print('end')
```

cell 2

```py
is_cancel_request = True
```

I also used code with *asyncio* like

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(some_async_function(i))
or 
syncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(some_async_function(1), loop)
```

but it also unsuccess. I would be thankful for any advice how to make it works

---

UPDATE: is there any working way to start code in one jupyter cell and then launch code in the next cell? could you provide a sample code or share a link ? I did not find any working sample in google (

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your code is not an asynchronous task in essence. You are more likely to be able to manually modify the attribute values in the thread when the thread loops, but this is contrary to the Python code.

The code is executed line by line, so the loop cannot be terminated, and the code cannot run even if you want to change it to true.

I suggest your `is_cancel_request` variable can be obtained from other files, or it can be written as a thread, so that the two threads can interact with each other, rather than creating a new cell to block it.

Comment: The main goal is run async code in one cell and when the code in the first cell continue to work, launch the another code in next (second) cell

Comment: However, the code is executed line by line, and the while loop will not execute the next content until it has ended. This requirement you mentioned violates the code running rules. This cannot be completed. You can only try to design this variable as the content of another thread, and then let the main thread obtain the variable, instead of manually modifying it in the file.